# Update or Insert on a Table based on a column value

Tags: insert, plsql, cursors

I have two tables BASE and DAILY as shown below:

```
BASE    
Cust ID  IP address
1        10.5.5.5
2        10.5.5.50
3        10.5.5.6

DAILY   
Cust ID  IP address
1        10.5.5.5
2        10.5.5.70
4        10.5.5.67
```

The table DAILY is periodically refreshed every 24 hours. Now for every `Cust Id` in BASE I have to check if the IP address is modified in DAILY. If yes then update the row in BASE.
All the new entries in DAILY have to be inserted into BASE.

I have tried this using a Cursor comparing and then updating and then another cursor for insertion.

But it is taking lot of time.

What is the best possible way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use `MERGE` depending on your database system.
SQL Server syntax would be

```
MERGE INTO BASE B
USING DAILY D
ON D.CustId = B.CustId
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (CustId, Ip) VALUES (D.CustId, D.Ip)
WHEN MATCHED AND D.Ip <> B.Ip THEN
UPDATE SET B.Ip = D.Ip;
```

Oracle PL/SQL syntax seems to be much the same, take a look [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/merge-statement.php)

Comment: @user2513495 please be aware that depending on you database system MERGE may or may not be atomic, so ensure you take appropiate action in terms of transaction and locking etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to update all your `BASE` table, use an UPDATE to update all the rows in your `BASE` table.

```
UPDATE `BASE`
SET `IP address` = (SELECT `IP address`
                    FROM DAILY
                    WHERE DAILY.`Cust ID` = `BASE`.`Cust ID`);
```

Then, use this INSERT INTO query to insert new values that not exists in your table `BASE`.

```
INSERT INTO `BASE`
SELECT `Cust ID`, `IP address`
FROM DAILY
WHERE DAILY.`Cust ID` NOT IN (SELECT `Cust ID` FROM BASE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SQL>
  declare
  begin
  for i in (select * from daily where ip_add not in (select ip_add from base))
  loop
  update base set ip_add=i.ip_add where custid=i.custid;
  end loop;
  end;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

  SQL> select * from base;

    CUSTID IP_ADD
---------- ----------
         1 10..5.5.5
         2 10..5.5.20   -- updated value from base where ip_add is different 
         3 10..5.5.6

 SQL> select * from base  ;

    CUSTID IP_ADD
---------- ----------
         1 10..5.5.5
         2 10..5.5.20
         4 10..5.5.62
```

SQL>